# How to detect if "touch alternatives" are enabled on iOS app running on an Mac M1?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I would like to know in my code if "touche alternatives" are enabled or not.

I added the file "com.apple.uikit.inputalternatives.plist" to set enabled at the start of the app but I want to know after.

I was looking in apple documentation(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple-silicon/providing_touch_gesture_equivalents_using_touch_alternatives) but I found nothing.

How I can do it?

[touch alternatives setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8x7HX.png)